# How to get the items orders by the customer in the order collection?

Tags: magento2.2, sales-order, order-collection

I need to get the collection of orders with the the items ordered by using the customer ID. But I am not getting the items ordered in my collection. Please help.

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $captinId)->setOrder('entity_id',$direction)->setPageSize($pageSize)->setCurPage($currentPage);
                $orderResult = $order->getData();
return $orderResult;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way:

```
$captinId = 2;
$direction = 'ASC';
$pageSize = 20;
$currentPage = 1;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderItemCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\Collection')
    ->setOrder('entity_id', $direction)
    ->setPageSize($pageSize)
    ->setCurPage($currentPage);

$orderItemCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    'sales_order',
    'sales_order.entity_id=main_table.order_id',
    ['increment_id']
)->where('sales_order.customer_id=?', $captinId);
$orderResult = $orderItemCollection->getData();
```

***Note***: Avoid to use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, now I am getting the products but I want to get them as an array of items. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$lastyear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 year"));
$orderCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection');
$orderCollection->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',123456)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status','complete')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq'  => $lastyear))->load();

echo "<pre>";print_r($orderCollection->getData()); exit;
```

Then you need to load the order items by order ID.

```
<?php
$orderid = 2;

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface')->load($orderid);

//Loop through each item and fetch data
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item)
{
   //fetch whole item information
   print_r($item->getData());

   //Or fetch specific item information
   echo $item->getId();
   echo $item->getProductType();
   echo $item->getQtyOrdered();
   echo $item->getPrice(); 

}
?>
```

Comment: But this also does not get the order items in my response.

Comment: I have updated the answer.